# $ (e^{2x})=(e^x)^2$ Can Some one explain how these two are the same? I know it is trick, but I cannot see how it fits into the exponent rules.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ (e^{2x})=(e^x)^2$

Can Some one explain how these two are the same? I know it is trick, but I cannot see how it fits into the exponent rules.

Comment: What exponent rules do you know?

Comment: Not a trick. Just laws of exponents: $(e^x)^2$=$(e^x)(e^x)$=$e^{x+x}$=$e^{2x}$

Comment: I'm curious about your username.

Comment: This is generally called the "power rule" or "powers to powers" rule: http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/exponents/review/review.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asuuming you're familiar with $e^x\cdot e^y=e^{x+y}$ then $e^x\cdot e^x=e^{x+x}=e^{2x}$.